# MySQL - Update field statement query/error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, where-clause

The below statement returns the results I want to change perfectly *"Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 2,018 total, Query took 0.0781 sec)"* :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `ID` IN

(SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE (`meta_key` = 'expires') AND (`meta_value` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND (`meta_value` IS NOT NULL));
```

However the below returns an error *"#1292 - Truncated incorrect datetime value: ''"*, when I try and update that result sets 'post_status' field ... Where is the error in my 2nd statements syntax please (below) ?

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status`='draft' WHERE `ID` IN

(SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE (`meta_key` = 'expires') AND (`meta_value` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND (`meta_value` IS NOT NULL));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What type is meta_value?

Comment: Are you running that on different databases?

Comment: meta_value is longtext

Comment: No same database. Just different tables within it.

Comment: What do you mean by different tables? The table names are the same in both queries.

Comment: I'm returning data from the wp_postmeta table to the query against wp_posts table.

Comment: The issue isn't with the second part of the statement as the SELECT * works fine.

Comment: What does this return? SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value`<=(SELECT Now() - INTERVAL 1 day)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET    `post_status` = 'draft' 
WHERE  `id` IN (SELECT `post_id` 
                FROM   `wp_postmeta` 
                WHERE  ( `meta_key` = 'expires' ) 
                       AND ( Str_to_date(`meta_value`, '%Y-%m-%d  %h:%i:%s') <= 
                             Now() 
                             - INTERVAL 1 day 
                           ) 
                       AND ( `meta_value` IS NOT NULL ));
```

Or use join

```
UPDATE a SET a.post_status='draft' FROM `wp_posts` a 
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` b ON a.ID=b.post_id 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'expires'
AND (`meta_value` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND (`meta_value` IS NOT NULL))
```

You could try to convert longtext to datetime:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Comment: Thanks ... But that only returns 89 rows, not the 2,018 I find with my original statement in the 'wp_postmeta' table.

Comment: Example data for meta_value column:   2013-07-24 19:03:00     . It also has other non date related values such as '3', 'default' etc.  But all the dates are in the 2013-07-24 19:03:00 format.  Thanks

Comment: SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE (`meta_key` = 'expires') AND (`meta_value` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND (`meta_value` IS NOT NULL);   Returns 2,018 rows absolutely fine ... I just can't get the first UPDATE part of the query to work ...

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `wp_posts` INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id ' at line 1

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `wp_posts` a INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` b ON a.ID=b.post_id WHERE `meta_k' at line 1

Comment: I now get a different error ... #1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '2013-08-04 23:59:59' for function str_to_date

Comment: Can anyone please help?